# How can I treat a file not a binary (git)

Tags: git

I have a file call a.uni, and I have to merge the solution.
But git treat a.uni as binary file.
When I merge the solution, it always shows:

warning: Cannot merge binary files: a.uni (HEAD vs. 549af46... test)
error: could not apply 549af46... test
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add ' or 'git rm '
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
Can somebody else help me!!!
thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, what's in the .uni file? And what are the contents of your .gitattributes file?

Comment: Actually, it's just a text in the uni file, and there is no .gitattributes in my repository.

Answer (score 4):

Since your `.uni` file is actually a text file, I suppose it must have some NUL character in it (see "[How to determine if Git handles a file as binary or as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119956/how-to-determine-if-git-handles-a-file-as-binary-or-as-text)").

It depends on how you want to manage the merge.

As mentioned in "[Tell git not to merge binary files but to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920594/tell-git-not-to-merge-binary-files-but-to-choose)", you can specify a merge manager in a `.gitattributes` file which will merge according to your policy.

At least, as in "[why does git treat some cpp files as binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735663/why-does-git-treat-some-cpp-files-as-binary)", you can try and specify (still ion the `.gitattributes` file):

```
*.uni -text crlf diff
```

---

For Unicode files, looking at "[Can I make git recognize a UTF-16 file as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777949/can-i-make-git-recognize-a-utf-16-file-as-text)", you can:

- either define a custom diff or merge tool supporting that format:
  `git config --global diff.tool vimdiff ; git difftool commit1 commit2`
- or define an attribute like:
  *.uni diff merge -crlf

You should also make sure:

- you have git1.7.10+ (which has better UTF-8 support)
- have set the utf-8 settings: see "[git, msysgit, accents, utf-8, the definitive answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5855213/6309)".

Comment: Now, I know why git treat my file as binary. Because it is a unicode file. But I still don't know how to solve that~~~

Comment: @user1584490 did you try the `*.uni -text crlf diff` gitattributes directive?

Comment: @user1584490 I have edited my answer to address the unicode nature of your `*.uni` files.

Comment: Is '-' sign a typo? '-text' means binary, but we want to set file as text. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim at the time (2011), the justification from the OP http://stackoverflow.com/q/4735663/6309 was "The `-text` part was needed to keep git from converting lineends, even though `core.autocrlf` is set to `false`". Nowadays (2016, git 2.8+), I would remove the `-text` and try it again, with `core.autocrlf` still set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Did the encoding type of the .uni file change (e.g. UTF-8 to ANSI)? Git doesn't seem to be able to compare/merge files of different encoding types. See the [answer I gave on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855712/git-treats-text-file-as-a-binary/21170043#21170043).